# unable to assign Null values to a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I was working on a dataset where I found some null values. It's basically a Book Recommendation System. I have a column Author with author names with some null values. I used selenium to extract the Author's name using the Title. I stored the name in a list.

Now, I wish to enter these authors' names into my data frame, at the indexes where the actual column author is having null values.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

[image: Dataset Image]

[image: Selenium Code.]

List b contains all the authors' names extracted using selenium. List nan contains indexes of the missing values of the Author column.

[image: Code I tried to assign the values]

[image: Indexes of the missing values in book data frame Author column]

Comment: Aside - consider more informative names than `b` and `nan`.

Comment: How are you matching the list with data frame column values? This attempts to assign all `NaN` author column values with all the author list values. Is author list the same length as missing values in author column?

Comment: Well, that the part I am unable to proceed further. I am trying to assign the values in the list b to book["Author"] column with nan index. Will attach an image with the post for the nan

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the author list is *same* length as missing values, you could `zip` through both lists for assignment:

```py
for x, y in zip(authors_nan_indices, authors_list):
    book["Author"][x] = y
```

But in Pandas, aim for vectorized operations over looping:

```py
book.loc[pd.isnull(book["Author"]), "Author"] = authors_list
```

Or with `numpy.where` using equality since `NaN` != `NaN`

```py
book["Author"] = np.where(
    book["Author"] == book["Author"],
    book["Author"], 
    np.array(authors_list)
)
```